# android - using BoltsFramework's continueWith and onSuccess methods with void methods

Tags: android, asynchronous, tcpclient, bolts-framework

I have two methods in my `TcpClient`. first one is `startListener`, and after that I do `connect`. both of them return `void`.

In my current `TcpClient` implementation, app crashes if I do `startListener` and then `connect` right after it (I guess there needs to be some time between them?). The implementation is [here](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-SimpleTCPLibrary/blob/master/Library/SimpleTCPLibrary/src/app/akexorcist/simpletcplibrary/ContinuousTCP.java#L143), from [SimpleTCPLibrary](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-SimpleTCPLibrary)  (he does `startListener` in `onStart()`, and has a **connect** button which triggers `connect`).

What I want to do is do `startListener`, and when is finishes with success -> do `connect`. I couldn't find any examples showing how to do this using **BoltsFramework's** `continueWith` or `onSuccess`.

Are there any examples out there?

Comment: Does [this help](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-databind-experiment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/realmdatabind/stuff/WriteElements.java#L23-L30)?

Answer (score 1):

You can always try

```
Task.delay(200).continueWith(new Continuation<Void, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object then(Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
        ... connect();
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Task.callInBackground(new Callable<Void>() { //or `Task.call` for synchronous
        @Override
        public Void call()
                throws Exception {
            /*... startListener */
            return null;
        }
    }).continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Void> then(Task<Void> ignored)
                throws Exception {
            return Task.delay(200);
        }
    }).continueWith(new Continuation<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void then(Task<Void> ignored)
                throws Exception {
            /*... connect */
            return null;
        }
    });
```

---

or with lambdas:

```
Task.call(() -> { TcpClient.startListener(); return null; })
    .continueWithTask(ignored -> Task.delay(200))
    .continueWith(ignored -> { TcpClient.connect(); return null; });
```